# Styling INPUT buttons in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've created a CSS button style for my button `inputs`, but it is not behaving correctly in Internet Explorer. In IE7 and IE8, the `:active` class only applies if I click on the padded area around the text. If I click on the text in the button, the :`active` class is not applied, and instead the text just shifts right by a pixel. My css works correctly in Firefox and Chrome.

Does anyone know what's going on here? Here is a jsFiddle with my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/timdmackey/fKBru/

Answer (score 0):

I would try switching away from an input with type="button" and instead do an  or something else. That could be the source of your pain.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible in this situation. I'm using an ecommerce platform (Shopify), and their cart system relies on having multiple submit buttons in one form, with various values. I've actually simplified my example in the jsFiddle, on my website I'm using generic elements or anchor links for many of my buttons.